# How to get HTML bgcolor of an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

If I have an element where the background colour is set via HTML as in:

```
<div id='foo' bgcolor='red'/>
```

How can I get the background colour via jquery? If I try `$('#foo').css( "background-color");` it returns rgba(0,0,0,0) which I assume is because it's looking for css but this was set in the html.

Comment: if you want to access attribute value `$('#foo').attr( "bgcolor");`

Comment: Aside from the issue, you *really* should not be usnig the `bgcolor` attribute as it's massively outdated. It also was never intended for use on `div` elements. Use CSS instead.

Comment: bgcolor was only for the body and table tags and is deprecated, you should use css instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#attr-bgcolor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery attr() function.

```js
let color = $('#foo').attr( "bgcolor");
alert(color);
```

```html
<div id="foo" bgcolor="red"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    console.log( document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("bgcolor"));
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute("bgcolor");

    // With Jquery
    var bgColorWithJquery = $('#demo').attr("bgcolor");
    console.log(bgColorWithJquery);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"/>

<p bgcolor="asdf" id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```